# Getting all the poll ids from a telegram BOT

Tags: telegram-bot

I'd like to know if there's a way to get all the ids from polls created by my bot into a list without having to run through all the chat history.

I tried looking for a get_polls method but couldn't find the documentation about it.

Answer (score 0):

No, the [Bot API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api) does not provide such a functionality. You'll have to keep track yourself.